# Webhooks - Validate the v3 request signature HUBSPOT

Tags: php, webhooks, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api

I am trying to connect a Hubspot CRM with my internal application, to send values from Hubspot to my app using Webhooks, with Authentication: Hubspot app id.
I have been using this: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/webhooks/validating-requests.
But the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUBSPOT_SIGNATURE_V3'] does not match my hashed string.

Here is the code:

```
$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; //returns: POST
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // returns: /hubspot/webhook.php
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
//returns: {"email":"test@gmail.com","field1":null,"field2":null,"field3":null,"field4":null}
$request_timestamp = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUBSPOT_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP'];// returns: 1679654017505
$string = utf8_encode("{$request_method}{$request_uri}{$request_body}{$request_timestamp}"); //POST/hubspot/webhook.php{"email":"test@gmail.com","field1":null,"field2":null,"field3":null,"field4":null}1679654017505
$HUBSPOT_APP_SECRET = '...';
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $HUBSPOT_APP_SECRET, true); //returns odd characters: ���_*�...
$encoded = base64_encode($hash);
$valid = hash_equals($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUBSPOT_SIGNATURE_V3'], $encoded);
if($valid == 1) {
    echo 'yes';
}else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

In the end, it returns 'no'. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, the problem was the secret key. That's a private app key! "pat-na1" stands for Private App Token in North America.

The secret keys the documentation is referring to are developer apps where you are given a client ID and client secret key. Developer app secrets are in the UUID format. Here's a link to how to create a developer app:

https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/creating-an-app

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in the function in the question. Here is the function I wrote which works for me:

```
function check_auth( $request )
    {
        $secret = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xx..'; // Use Client Secret Here! The common mistake it to use App secret here!!!!
        $hs_signature = $request->get_header('X-HubSpot-Signature-v3');
        $hs_timestamp = $request->get_header('X-HubSpot-Request-Timestamp');
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $str = $request->get_method() . $url . $request->get_body() . $hs_timestamp;
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $str, $secret, true);
        $encoded_hash = base64_encode($hash);
        return hash_equals($hs_signature, $encoded_hash);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! The documentation mentions using the request *URI*, but you have to use the full request *URL*. These are not the same thing (at least not in Java servlet land)